# How can I know the allocated memory size of a std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector, std

I understand that we can use `size()` function to obtain the vector size, for example:

```
   std::vector<in> abc;
   abc.resize(3);
   abc.size();
```

The my question is how can I know the memory size of a vector? Take an example:

```
std::vector<int> abc;
abc.reserve(7);
//the size of memory that has been allocated for abc
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: Note that `vector<bool>` is a special case, you cannot assume its size to be `sizeof(bool) * abc.capacity()`. See  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use the member function [`capacity()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity) to obtain the allocated capacity

```
std::vector<int> abc;
abc.reserve(7);
std::cout << abc.capacity() << std::endl;
```

To get the memory allocated by in bytes, You can do:

```
sizeof(int) * abc.capacity();
```

This is given, that you know your `value_type` is `int`. If you don't

```
sizeof(decltype(abc.back())) * abc.capacity();
```

Comment: Note to reader that the size returned by `capazcity` (and by `size`) is in number of elements, not in bytes if memory.

Comment: or more generally `sizeof(decltype(abc.front()) * abc.capacity)`

Comment: Does the size of an object include the padding?

Comment: @mksteve yes. It does.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer is that you can't.  Others have suggested ways that will often work, but you can't depend on `capacity` reflecting in any way the actual memory allocated.

For one thing, the heap will often allocate more memory than was requested.  This has to do with optimizations against fragmenting, etc...  `vector` has no way of knowing how much memory was actually allocated, only what it requested.

So `capacity` at best gives you a very rough estimate.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `capacity` member function - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity

Answer (score 0):

There are strong statements on the memory being contiguous, and so the size is

```
sizeof( abc[0] ) * abc.capacity();
```

or

```
(  (char*)(&abc[1]) - (char*)(&abc[0] ) ) * abc.capacity();
```

Comment: Why suggest the second method? It's more complicated, offers no advantage to the first, and I think it's technically UB if the array does not contain at least 2 elements. The first is nice.

Comment: You can't depend on sizeof(abc[0]) == sizeof(T).  Operator [] can return a proxy object.  You'd be better off with `value_type`.

Comment: @CrazyEddie: In the case which you are probably thinking of, `vector<bool>`, you can't count on `sizeof(value_type) * capacity()` being the actual amount of memory allocated either.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - No.  A vector of any type can return a proxy if Allocator::reference is such.

Comment: @CrazyEddie: Yes, of course. But hopefully homemade libraries don't follow the horrible example of `vector<bool>`. Either way, `sizeof(value_type)` doesn't help you here.

Answer (score 0):

Since std::vector can store complex objects (such as std::string), which have their internal memory management and may allocate additional memory, determining the total memory usage can be hard.

For a vector containing simple objects such as **int**, the suggested solution using **capacity** and **sizeof** will work though.